# Error de interrupcion a play()

Tags: javascript

**Código 1:**

```
function finEvento()
{
  sonido.pause();
  sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/principal.mp3");
  sonido.removeEventListener("ended", finEvento);
  sonido.play();
}
```

**Error**

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
> by a call to pause().

**Código 2:**

```
function finEvento()
{
   sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/principal.mp3");
   sonido.removeEventListener("ended", finEvento);
   sonido.play();
}
```

**Error**

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
> by a new load request.

En ambos errores, lo marca en la siguiente linea:

```
sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/principal.mp3");
```

En una función ejecutada por el **evento** `click` de un `div` tengo esto:

```
div.addEventListener("click", function(){
    configurarAudio();
});

function configurarAudio()
{
    sonido.pause();
            
    sonido.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        finEvento();
    });
            
    sonido.currentTime = 0;
    sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/error.mp3");
    sonido.play();
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando termine de reproducir el audio del "error.mp3" mediante el **evento** `ended` ejecutar la función `finEvento()` para reproducir el audio "principal.mp3"

Como soluciono eso??

Comment: as intentado hacer un `audio.currentTime = 0;` antes de asignar el source?

Comment: @Bryro ya lo hice y sigue marcando los mimos errores

Comment: Puede que esto te ayude https://stackoverflow.com/q/36803176/13419694